# Как постепенно уменьшать элемент при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

т.е. чтобы он не уменьшался при достижении определённого уровня, а на протяжении всего движения до этого уровня постепенно уменьшался.

Comment: подписаться на событие скролла и в зависимости от положения пересчитывать нужные размеры